# Plotly.js hover across multiple subplots

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a plotly.js graph with multiple subplots that share an x-axis as in https://plot.ly/javascript/subplots/#stacked-subplots-with-a-shared-x-axis

I'm trying to hover across all of the subplots so that the values of all of the points with the same x value are displayed at once.

I've attempted to solve this by calling Plotly.Fx.hover on each subplot, but it only seems to take effect for the last subplot on which it is called.
http://codepen.io/john-soklaski/pen/adQwBa

The code I tried is:

```
Plotly.Fx.hover('myDiv', {xval: 2, curveNumber: 0}, "xy")
Plotly.Fx.hover('myDiv', {xval: 2, curveNumber: 1}, "xy2")
```

Ideally the API would be such that I could do this in a single call:

```
Plotly.Fx.hover('myDiv', [{xval: 2, curveNumber: 0, subplot: "xy"}, {xval: 2, curveNumber: 1, subplot: "xy2"}])
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is old, but this functionality has been added: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/301

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plotly.plot('myDiv', data, layout);
graph = document.getElementById('myDiv');
graph.on('plotly_hover', function(eventdata) {
    if (eventdata.xvals) {
        Plotly.Fx.hover(graph, {
            xval: eventdata.xvals[0]
        }, ['xy', 'x2y2', 'x3y3', 'x4y4']);
    }
});
```

For multiple subplots add the axis labels array also. 
In this case

> ['xy', 'x2y2', 'x3y3', 'x4y4']

In this way you can get coupled hover events for subplots in a div

Comment: I get `TypeError: graph.on is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass the visible subplots as the third arg to `Plotly.Fx.hover` func.

This worked for me:

```js
chartContainer.current.on('plotly_hover', function () {
  var points = eventdata.points[0]
  var pointNum = points.pointNumber
  Plotly.Fx.hover(
    chartContainer.current,
    props.data.map((_, i) => ({
      curveNumber: i,
      pointNumber: pointNum
    })),
    Object.keys((chartContainer.current)._fullLayout._plots))
})
```

`chartContainer.current` is the `div` here.

`Object.keys((chartContainer.current)._fullLayout._plots)` will return the visible plots, for example: `['xy', 'xy2'...]`